# Subtract time from Business hours only (VB.net)

Tags: vb.net, date, time, datagridview

I am finding this concept hard to figure out. The scenario should go like this:

The picture is a datagridview contains 3 columns (Today, Tomorrow and The next day)

Let's say I've subtract the hours but if I will plot on 8am on column No. 1 (Tomorrow) then the difference will start on 17:00 (5pm) Column No. 0 (Today.

I only need the snippet code since I know the source code for subtraction already.

Datagridview :

[image]

EDIT: To avoid confusion, how to plot 14:00  on Today column 0 of Datagridview if I start to subtract from 08:00 of Column 1. (Only Business Hours from 8am to 5pm)

EDIT2: Source code as requested:

```
    For i As Integer = 0 To frmSchedule.DatagridSchedule.Rows.Count - 1
            If cmbSelectAvailableTIme.SelectedItem.Equals(frmSchedule.DatagridSchedule.Rows(i).HeaderCell.Value) Then
                frmSchedule.DatagridSchedule.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value = Info1 & Environment.NewLine & Info2 & Environment.NewLine & Info3 & Environment.NewLine & txtboxAccessories.Text.ToString & Environment.NewLine & INfo4
                frmSchedule.DatagridSchedule.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True

                Dim datetime1 As DateTime = cmbSelectAvailableTIme.Text
                Dim newDateTime As DateTime = datetime1.Subtract(New TimeSpan(0, TimeEstimate.Text, 0)).ToString("HH:mm")

                StatusBillboard.DataGridViewBillboard.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value = Info1
                StatusBillboard.DataGridViewBillboard.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value = Info2
                StatusBillboard.DataGridViewBillboard.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value = Info2
                StatusBillboard.DataGridViewBillboard.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value = INfo4
                StatusBillboard.DataGridViewBillboard.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value = "Invoice"
                StatusBillboard.DataGridViewBillboard.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value = "MP"
                StatusBillboard.DataGridViewBillboard.Rows(i).Cells(6).Value = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") & " " & newDateTime



                For i_scan As Integer = 0 To FrmFinalApproval.DatagridFinalApproval.Rows.Count - 1
                    For i_inspection As Integer = 0 To PreInspection.DatagridInspection.Rows.Count - 1
                        If cmbSelectAvailableTIme.SelectedItem.Equals(FrmFinalApproval.DatagridFinalApproval.Rows(i_scan).HeaderCell.Value) Then
                            cmbSelectAvailableTIme.Text = ""
                            cmbSelectAvailableTIme.Text = Format(newDateTime, "HH:mm")
                            Dim selectedIndex As Integer = cmbSelectAvailableTIme.FindStringExact(cmbSelectAvailableTIme.Text)
                            FrmFinalApproval.DatagridFinalApproval.Rows(selectedIndex).Cells(0).Value = Info1 & Environment.NewLine & Info2 & Environment.NewLine & Info3 & Environment.NewLine & txtboxAccessories.Text.ToString & Environment.NewLine & INfo4
                            FrmFinalApproval.DatagridFinalApproval.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True
                            '   cell.Style.BackColor = Color.LightSalmon
                            FrmFinalApproval.DatagridFinalApproval.Rows(selectedIndex).Cells(0).Style.BackColor = Color.LightYellow
                            FinalGridview = FrmFinalApproval.DatagridFinalApproval.Rows(selectedIndex).Cells(0).RowIndex
                            FInalGridview2 = FrmFinalApproval.DatagridFinalApproval.Rows(selectedIndex).Cells(0).ColumnIndex

                        End If



                        If cmbSelectAvailableTIme.SelectedItem.Equals(PreInspection.DatagridInspection.Rows(i_inspection).HeaderCell.Value) Then
                            cmbSelectAvailableTIme.Text = ""

                            cmbSelectAvailableTIme.Text = Format(newDateTime, "HH:mm")

                            Dim selectedIndex As Integer = cmbSelectAvailableTIme.FindStringExact(cmbSelectAvailableTIme.Text)

                            PreInspection.DatagridInspection.Rows(selectedIndex).Cells(0).Value = Info1 & Environment.NewLine & Info2 & Environment.NewLine & Info3 & Environment.NewLine & txtboxAccessories.Text.ToString & Environment.NewLine & INfo4
                            PreInspection.DatagridInspection.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True

                            PreInspection.DatagridInspection.Rows(selectedIndex).Cells(0).Style.BackColor = Color.LightYellow
                            carwashInspect = PreInspection.DatagridInspection.Rows(selectedIndex).Cells(0).RowIndex
                            Carwashinspect2 = PreInspection.DatagridInspection.Rows(selectedIndex).Cells(0).ColumnIndex
                        End If

                    Next
                Next

                Dim datetime2 As DateTime = cmbSelectAvailableTIme.Text
                Dim newDateTime2 As DateTime = datetime2.Subtract(New TimeSpan(0, TimeEstimate.Text, 0)).ToString("HH:mm")
                cmbSelectAvailableTIme.Text = newDateTime2.ToString("HH:mm")



        For i_scan2 As Integer = 0 To FrmCandCollection.DatagridCandCollection.Rows.Count - 1
                    For i_carwash As Integer = 0 To Carwash.DatagridCarwash.Rows.Count - 1
                        If cmbSelectAvailableTIme.SelectedItem.Equals(Carwash.DatagridCarwash.Rows(i_scan2).HeaderCell.Value) Then
                            Dim selectedIndex As Integer = cmbSelectAvailableTIme.FindStringExact(Carwash.DatagridCarwash.Rows(i_scan2).HeaderCell.Value)
                            FrmCandCollection.DatagridCandCollection.Rows(selectedIndex).Cells(0).Value = Info1 & Environment.NewLine & Info2 & Environment.NewLine & Info3 & Environment.NewLine & txtboxAccessories.Text.ToString & Environment.NewLine & INfo4
                            FrmCandCollection.DatagridCandCollection.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True
                            CandCGridview = FrmCandCollection.DatagridCandCollection.Rows(selectedIndex).Cells(0).RowIndex
                            CandCGridview2 = FrmCandCollection.DatagridCandCollection.Rows(selectedIndex).Cells(0).ColumnIndex
                        End If

                        If cmbSelectAvailableTIme.SelectedItem.Equals(Carwash.DatagridCarwash.Rows(i_carwash).HeaderCell.Value) Then


                            Dim selectedIndex As Integer = cmbSelectAvailableTIme.FindStringExact(Carwash.DatagridCarwash.Rows(i_carwash).HeaderCell.Value)

                            Carwash.DatagridCarwash.Rows(selectedIndex).Cells(0).Value = Info1 & Environment.NewLine & Info2 & Environment.NewLine & Info3 & Environment.NewLine & txtboxAccessories.Text.ToString & Environment.NewLine & INfo4
                            Carwash.DatagridCarwash.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True

                            CarwashGridview = Carwash.DatagridCarwash.Rows(selectedIndex).Cells(0).RowIndex
                            CarwashGridview2 = Carwash.DatagridCarwash.Rows(selectedIndex).Cells(0).ColumnIndex


                        End If

                    Next

                Next

                Dim datetime3 As DateTime = cmbSelectAvailableTIme.Text
                Dim newDateTime3 As DateTime = datetime3.Subtract(New TimeSpan(0, TimeEstimate.Text, 0)).ToString("HH:mm")
                cmbSelectAvailableTIme.Text = newDateTime3.ToString("HH:mm")





  For i_scan3 As Integer = 0 To frmAccounting.DatagridAccounting.Rows.Count - 1
                    For i_caraccessories As Integer = 0 To frmAccessories.DatagridviewAccessories.Rows.Count - 1
                        For i_cashier As Integer = 0 To frmCashier.DatagridCashier.Rows.Count - 1

                            If cmbSelectAvailableTIme.SelectedItem.Equals(frmAccounting.DatagridAccounting.Rows(i_scan3).HeaderCell.Value) Then
                                Dim selectedIndex As Integer = cmbSelectAvailableTIme.FindStringExact(frmAccounting.DatagridAccounting.Rows(i_scan3).HeaderCell.Value)
                                frmAccounting.DatagridAccounting.Rows(selectedIndex).Cells(0).Value = Info1 & Environment.NewLine & Info2 & Environment.NewLine & Info3 & Environment.NewLine & txtboxAccessories.Text.ToString & Environment.NewLine & INfo4
                                frmAccounting.DatagridAccounting.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True

                                AccountGridview = frmAccounting.DatagridAccounting.Rows(selectedIndex).Cells(0).RowIndex
                                AccountGridView2 = frmAccounting.DatagridAccounting.Rows(selectedIndex).Cells(0).ColumnIndex
                            End If

                            If cmbSelectAvailableTIme.SelectedItem.Equals(frmAccessories.DatagridviewAccessories.Rows(i_caraccessories).HeaderCell.Value) Then


                                Dim selectedIndex As Integer = cmbSelectAvailableTIme.FindStringExact(frmAccessories.DatagridviewAccessories.Rows(i_caraccessories).HeaderCell.Value)

                                frmAccessories.DatagridviewAccessories.Rows(selectedIndex).Cells(0).Value = Info1 & Environment.NewLine & Info2 & Environment.NewLine & Info3 & Environment.NewLine & txtboxAccessories.Text.ToString & Environment.NewLine & INfo4
                                frmAccessories.DatagridviewAccessories.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True
                                AccessoriesGridview = frmAccessories.DatagridviewAccessories.Rows(selectedIndex).Cells(0).RowIndex
                                AccessoriesGridview2 = frmAccessories.DatagridviewAccessories.Rows(selectedIndex).Cells(0).ColumnIndex
                            End If

                            If cmbSelectAvailableTIme.SelectedItem.Equals(frmCashier.DatagridCashier.Rows(i_cashier).HeaderCell.Value) Then
                                Dim selectedIndex As Integer = cmbSelectAvailableTIme.FindStringExact(frmCashier.DatagridCashier.Rows(i_cashier).HeaderCell.Value)

                                frmCashier.DatagridCashier.Rows(selectedIndex).Cells(0).Value = Info1 & Environment.NewLine & Info2 & Environment.NewLine & Info3 & Environment.NewLine & txtboxAccessories.Text.ToString & Environment.NewLine & INfo4
                                frmCashier.DatagridCashier.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True
                                AccessoriesGridview = frmCashier.DatagridCashier.Rows(selectedIndex).Cells(0).RowIndex
                                AccessoriesGridview2 = frmCashier.DatagridCashier.Rows(selectedIndex).Cells(0).ColumnIndex
                            End If
                        Next
                    Next
                Next


                Dim datetime4 As DateTime = cmbSelectAvailableTIme.Text
                Dim newDateTime4 As DateTime = datetime4.Subtract(New TimeSpan(0, TimeEstimate.Text, 0)).ToString("HH:mm")
                cmbSelectAvailableTIme.Text = newDateTime4.ToString("HH:mm")

 For i_scan4 As Integer = 0 To FrmInsurance.DatagridInsurance.Rows.Count - 1
                    If cmbSelectAvailableTIme.SelectedItem.Equals(FrmInsurance.DatagridInsurance.Rows(i_scan4).HeaderCell.Value) Then

                        Dim selectedIndex As Integer = cmbSelectAvailableTIme.FindStringExact(cmbSelectAvailableTIme.Text)

                        FrmInsurance.DatagridInsurance.Rows(selectedIndex).Cells(0).Value = Info1 & Environment.NewLine & Info2 & Environment.NewLine & Info3 & Environment.NewLine & txtboxAccessories.Text.ToString & Environment.NewLine & INfo4
                        FrmInsurance.DatagridInsurance.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True
                        InsuranceGridView = FrmInsurance.DatagridInsurance.Rows(selectedIndex).Cells(0).RowIndex
                        InsuranceGridview2 = FrmInsurance.DatagridInsurance.Rows(selectedIndex).Cells(0).ColumnIndex
                    End If

                Next


                Dim datetime5 As DateTime = cmbSelectAvailableTIme.Text
                Dim newDateTime5 As DateTime = datetime5.Subtract(New TimeSpan(0, TimeEstimate.Text, 0)).ToString("HH:mm")
                cmbSelectAvailableTIme.Text = newDateTime5.ToString("HH:mm")

                For i_scan5 As Integer = 0 To frmFinancing.DatagridFinancing.Rows.Count - 1
                    If cmbSelectAvailableTIme.SelectedItem.Equals(frmFinancing.DatagridFinancing.Rows(i_scan5).HeaderCell.Value) Then

                        Dim selectedIndex As Integer = cmbSelectAvailableTIme.FindStringExact(cmbSelectAvailableTIme.Text)

                        frmFinancing.DatagridFinancing.Rows(selectedIndex).Cells(0).Value = Info1 & Environment.NewLine & Info2 & Environment.NewLine & Info3 & Environment.NewLine & txtboxAccessories.Text.ToString & Environment.NewLine & INfo4
                        frmFinancing.DatagridFinancing.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True
                        FinancingGridView = frmFinancing.DatagridFinancing.Rows(selectedIndex).Cells(0).RowIndex
                        FinancingGRidview2 = frmFinancing.DatagridFinancing.Rows(selectedIndex).Cells(0).ColumnIndex
                    End If

                Next

                Dim datetime6 As DateTime = cmbSelectAvailableTIme.Text
                Dim newDateTime6 As DateTime = datetime6.Subtract(New TimeSpan(0, TimeEstimate.Text, 0)).ToString("HH:mm")
                cmbSelectAvailableTIme.Text = newDateTime6.ToString("HH:mm")

                For i_scan6 As Integer = 0 To frmINvoice.DatagridInvoice.Rows.Count - 1
                    If cmbSelectAvailableTIme.SelectedItem.Equals(frmINvoice.DatagridInvoice.Rows(i_scan6).HeaderCell.Value) Then

                        Dim selectedIndex As Integer = cmbSelectAvailableTIme.FindStringExact(cmbSelectAvailableTIme.Text)

                        frmINvoice.DatagridInvoice.Rows(selectedIndex).Cells(0).Value = Info1 & Environment.NewLine & Info2 & Environment.NewLine & Info3 & Environment.NewLine & txtboxAccessories.Text.ToString & Environment.NewLine & INfo4
                        frmINvoice.DatagridInvoice.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True
                        InvoiceGridView = frmINvoice.DatagridInvoice.Rows(selectedIndex).Cells(0).RowIndex
                        InvoiceGridView2 = frmINvoice.DatagridInvoice.Rows(selectedIndex).Cells(0).ColumnIndex
                    End If

                Next







            End If


        Next
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish. So when subtracting, you want to ignore the time between 5pm and 8am the next day?

Comment: @p3tch: To make it clearer, I've plot 08:00 at Tomorrow Column where the subtraction of 3 hours (as input) will happen on 17:00 Today column as Business hours. Its a client system for their time table report

Comment: In short, the computation is backwards where how to automatically detect to subtract starting 17:00 on column 0

Comment: I too am struggling to understand this. Would you edit the above clarifications into your post (ideally invisibly rather than as Edit: postscripts) so that readers can have a better idea of the problem? Also if you have no code presently, it is a good idea to try - "I need the code for this" questions tend to get closed here.

Comment: `... I know the source code for subtraction already.`. Post the code you have to show some effort from your side.

Comment: @halfer: Kindly check my edit post, I'm sorry for unintentional confusion.

Comment: Your code formatting is rather broken, as you can see. For each section (e.g. `InsuranceBased:`) put a line break afterwards so that the code renderer reads it correctly.

Comment: @haifer: Done already. :)

Comment: Guys, for another time. If I plot 08:00 on Tomorrow and subtract for 3 hours. My another form having datagridview must be 15:00 on column 0 (today) plotted ( because 16:00-19:00) is no longer a business hours., I repeat, the computation is backward.

Comment: Why no one could understand my problem? I'm already out of luck to find any similar scenario.

Comment: @p3tch:I analyzed your comment, and yes something related for that.

Comment: No one manage to help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on when business hours end on one day and start on the next, just need to check if the new time is before the start of the next day's business hours and if it is, then subtract the additional hours.

Here's an example

End Time: 09:00
Time Estimate : 05:00  (5 hours)

Subtract 5 hours from end time to get start time - 04:00

Is 04:00 before that day's business hours? Yes

If business hours are 08:00 to 17:00 then subtract the number of non business hours.

This code should do it.

```
Dim duration As New TimeSpan
Dim startTimeOfBusinessHours As Integer = 8
Dim endTimeOfBusinessHours As Integer = 17
'calculate the number of hours between end and start of business hours
Dim nonBusinessHourseBetweeDays As Integer = 24 + startTimeOfBusinessHours - endTimeOfBusinessHours
'parse duration as timespan
duration = TimeSpan.Parse(TimeEstimate.Text)
'create datetime for start of business hours of the date in DateTime1
Dim businessHoursStart As Date = New Date(datetime1.Year, datetime1.Month, datetime1.Day, startTimeOfBusinessHours, 0, 0, 0)
'calculate the Start time for the plot
Dim newDateTime As DateTime = datetime1.Subtract(duration)
'If the start time of the plot is before the start of busines hours on the end day then subtract
'the number of non business hourse
If newDateTime < businessHoursStart Then
    newDateTime.Subtract(New TimeSpan(nonBusinessHourseBetweeDays, 0, 0))
End If
```

If your working week is not 7 days, then you will need to add more code to allow for non business days as well.

Comment: It seems the code does not work correctly. The expectation result is different; 8AM to be 8AM instead of 4:30PM (minus 30 minutes)

Comment: I'm sorry, I dont understand your comment. I think our first languages are different :-) OK So for these examples, what results do you expect? 1) End time of 10:15 with a length of 5 hours 30 minutes. 2) End time of 09:00 with a length of 3 hours. 3) End time of 08:15 with a length of 1 hour 30 minutes?  Thanks.